# Running into library issues importing snowflake python connector into lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build, snowflake-connector-python, as a lambda layer to execute SQL on Snowflake. I am using the dependencies listed here to build the zip file with dependencies on Amazon linux EC2 instance - https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/main/tested_requirements/requirements_39.reqs

Python runtime version - 3.9 snowflake-connector-python - 3.0.4

I followed the recommended process to build the zip file with connector and dependencies and uploaded them as a lambda layer. However, when I run a simple app to test the import -

```
import snowflake.connector
```

this is the error message -

> Response { "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function':
> /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by
> /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)",
> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId":
> "5245b8b3-bd72-4e8c-9ead-518418617d93",  "stackTrace": [] }

cryptography version I imported is the exact version listed in the git repo. Has anyone faced similar issues importing snowflake connector.

Thank you.

Comment: I figured out the issue..was creating the zip folder using AL2012 linux version. Once I change to AL2 which is the default lambda linux version, it worked fine. Thanks for checking-in!

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with creating the zip folder using AL2012 linux version. Once I change to AL2 which is the default lambda linux version, it worked fine. Thanks for checking-in!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html